# Passing Url parameter through OnSuccess callback

Tags: ajax.beginform

I need to use 2 parameters coming in the URL and use them within OnSuccess callback function.

This is the Url sent from server:

```
http://localhost:35325/?Message=ChangePasswordSuccess&param1=%23UserSettings
```

And I need param1 to be sent like that:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Manage", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Você tem certeza que deseja salvar a alteração?", OnSuccess = "close(Message, param1);" }))
```

Here I am getting a reference error saying that:
ReferenceError: param1 is not defined.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is the right way to go:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Manage", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Você tem certeza que deseja salvar a alteração?", OnSuccess = "close(Message, param1);" }))
```

thanks